# Average day and night temperature in excel

Tags: excel, date, time, excel-formula, formula

I have a large dataset of temperature and humidity readings, collected every half hour for a year. I'd like to get an average of day and night temperature, but my experiments with averageifs have so far failed. This is as far as I got.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Sheet1!D$7:D$17622,Sheet1!$C$7:$C$17622, ">="&$A21, Sheet1!$C$7:$C$17622,"<" &$A22)
```

The values in A21 and A22 are 6:00 and 18:00, formatted as h:mm.

This just returns a DIV/0! error - I don't have any zeros, so I don't know what the issue is.

I have exactly the same formula working with dates. Both formulas are drawing on the same input, entered into each cell like so:

```
1/02/2016  3:00:00 PM
```

I would be most grateful for any assistance (or if this is the wrong forum, let me know).

Comment: ...weird, I was ***just*** doing the same thing last week, with the end goal of calculating accuracy of forecasts to actual weather data, using Excel's `CORREL` function.  (...this isn't *Dave*, is it? lol)

Comment: I'm not quite clear if you have a date-time entered into a single cell, or a date, a time and am/pm entered into 3 separate cells?

Comment: They're all in one cell (that's the way my loggers make the files). And no, this isn't Dave...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems is the size of the ranges you are specifying.

<sub>From the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/averageifs-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690):</sub>

> **Syntax:**
>
> ```
> AVERAGEIFS(average_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2],...)
> ```
>
> The `AVERAGEIFS` function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> `Average_range`    *Required*. One or more cells to average, including numbers or names, arrays, or references that contain numbers.
>
> `Criteria_range1, criteria_range2, …`    Criteria_range1 is *required*, subsequent criteria_ranges are *optional*. 1 to 127 ranges in which to evaluate the associated criteria.
>
> `Criteria1, criteria2, …`    Criteria1 is *required*, subsequent criteria are *optional*. 1 to 127 criteria in the form of a number, expression, cell reference, or text that define which cells will be averaged. For example, criteria can be expressed as `32`, `"32"`, `">32"`, "`apples"`, or `B4`.
>
> ***Unlike the range and criteria arguments in the `AVERAGEIF` function, in `AVERAGEIFS` each criteria_range must be the same size and shape as sum_range***.

So, with `AVERAGEIFS`, `SUMIFS`, `COUNTIFS`, if the range to calculate (the fist paramater) is, for example, A1:`A10`, then **all** of criteria ranges that you specify also have to span 10 cells.

---

You may be incorrectly using `AVERAGEIFS` instead of `AVERAGEIF`.

- If you have a single row of criteria and want to average one or more rows of data , use `AVERAGEIF`.
- If you have multiple criteria (ie., before this time and after that time) and want to average one row of data, use `AVERAGEIFS`.

I don't believe you can use either for *multiple criteria + multiple data rows*.  If that's what you're trying to do, you may need to use `SUMIFS` and `COUNTIFS` for *each row* and then calculate an average from those.

---

**For example:**

- If you want to average daytime temperatures (between 06:00 and 18:00)
- times are stored in `A1:X1` like `00:00` to `23:00` (*and do **not** have dates attached to them, even if not 'visible')
- temperatures are stored in columns `A:X` (one day per row)
- and you want to calculate average daytime temperatures, for one day, which is stored on Row 2,

**... then you could use:**

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A2:X2,A1:X1,">="&6/24,A1:X1,"<&18/24)
```

**Note** that when taking totals based on start/end dates/times, it's generally best to use:

- **`>=` the Start date/time**, and,
- **`<` the End date/time**

...to prevents ***overlaps***.

Also, when getting into more complex formulas like this, be sure to **manually calculate** a few rows to compare and verify that you've correctly specified the formula criteria.

---

More Information:

- Office.com : [AVERAGEIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/averageifs-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690)
- Office.com : [AVERAGEIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/averageif-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642)
- Office.com : [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)
- Office.com : [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)
- Exceltip.com : [AVERAGEIFS, SUMIFS and COUNTIFS Functions in Microsoft Excel](http://www.exceltip.com/excel-formula-and-function/averageifs-sumifs-and-countifs-functions-in-microsoft-excel.html)

Comment: Thank-you so much - You mentioned the problem, which was that the criteria wouldn't match a cell with date and time. I used =TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1), SECOND(A1)) to extract the time and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

One problem that wasn't solved was how to get night averages (day worked fine). I was also wanting the averages for each season. Here's how I fixed that with an array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF((Sheet1!C$7:C$17622>=A$31)+(Sheet1!C$7:C$17622<A$32),IF(Sheet1!$B$7:$B$17622 >=$B31, IF(Sheet1!$B$7:$B$17622<$B32,Sheet1!D$7:D$17622))))
```

In Sheet1, column C is Time, Column B is Date/time, and D is temperature.

And:
A31 = 18:00  A32 = 6:00 (Night time)

B31 = 1/03/2016  B32 = 1/06/2016 (example range for season)