# Average daily max/min temperature if within date/time range in Excel

Tags: excel, time, max, average, min

I have the following array formula which calculates the average daily temperature for a season (outlined in more detail here: [Average day and night temperature in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49147935/average-day-and-night-temperature-in-excel)).

```
=AVERAGE(IF(Sheet1!$C$7:$C$17622>=$A$20,IF(Sheet1!$C$7:$C$17622<$A$21,IF(Sheet1!$B$7:$B$17622>=$B18,IF(Sheet1!$B$7:$B$17622<$B19,OFFSET(Sheet1!A$7:A$17622,0,(COLUMN(Sheet1!A$7)*3)))))))
```

The `OFFSET` function is to account for alternating columns of temperature and humidity for each site (site temperature/humidity are in columns in Sheet1; there are four columns for each site, hence the *3).

I can get the absolute maximum for each season by replacing `AVERAGE` with `MAX`.

However, I would like to obtain the average maximum/minimum daily and nightly temperatures for each season, but I cannot figure out how to do it (after several hours). I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me out here.

Sample data here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9brbxjbcrhjwrhc/Climate%20by%20season.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add 1 extra column to 'collect' you daily maximum temperature and 1 more column for daily minimum temperature. Then use the same `AVERAGE` or `AVERAGEIFS` formula to work on each of these column to obtain your intended results.

Hope that helps.  ( :

Comment: Thanks for that answer. It's definitely a solution, but one I was trying to avoid... It would be nice to have everything all in one function, rather than having to create extra columns. I essentially did what you've suggested.

Comment: Since we don't have your sample data, that's the best I have to propose. SInce You had mentioned it. You can.. actually 'group' the range in the `max()` formula by using a few `indirect()` and/or `offset()` function. IMHO, it do-able in a one-line formula & within the excel's 8192 characters limits. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51500725/why-is-the-match-function-not-working-how-anticipated-in-excel-with-array-formul) one, it's 2939 characters. ( :  || You may share the sample file to proceed.. god willing we can build one.

Comment: Sample data added - I already have the calculations I need at the moment, but if you're willing to have a shot at a formula, I (or someone else) might use it later on (I have another year's worth of data that I haven't touched yet...).

Comment: Honestly.. I didn't expect there is a separate daily sunrise & sunset data used for you calculation. It'd made my originally proposed one-line formula idea gone to scrap. :p  || A very structured approach towards your goal I'd say.. you have my thumbs up. [ :

Comment: Ha, all the same thanks for taking a look... That dataset nearly did my head in. I might attempt to do it in R next time.